# why mapPartitions does not see my val - SCALA/SPARK?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I define val like this :

```
  val config = Config(args) 
  val product_type = config.product_type
```

then  I send `product_type` as "`AA`"

and my code is this :

```
  val scores = df.mapPartitions(iterator => {
    val inputStream =
      if(product_type == "AA" ) {
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_aa.hdf5")
      }
      else {
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_bb.hdf5")
      } 
    val multiLayerNetwork: MultiLayerNetwork = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(inputStream, false)
    val wrapped: ParallelInference = new ParallelInference.Builder(multiLayerNetwork).build()
    val res = iterator.map(row => {
      wrapped.output(row).toDoubleVector
    })
    res
  })
```

But my `inputStream` equals "`my_bb.hdf5`" which is not correct. This value comes from else statement. So why my `product_type`  variable cant read in mappartition?

I print my `product_type`  value before code and I checked it , it is : "`AA`"

Comment: what is the default value of config?

Comment: it is empty : "" , I send this value via spark-submit sh

Comment: this is the value that is broadcasted to the executors. how do you send product_type as "AA"?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I think this `product_type` should be captured by closure without any issue.

Comment: `product_type` is a `val`. So, it can not be modified. If OP checked it to be "AA" at any point, then it must be "AA" everywhere.

Comment: It should, but is the "AA" value sent as program argument?

Comment: yep I send "AA" in submit sh file as a argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it occurs because of i get this variable from argument in spark submit.sh
and it can not read from mappartition.

It works like this:

```
  val scores =
    if (product_type  == "AA") {
      df.mapPartitions(iterator => {
        val inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("AA.hdf5")
        val multiLayerNetwork: MultiLayerNetwork = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(inputStream, false)
        val wrapped: ParallelInference = new ParallelInference.Builder(multiLayerNetwork).build()
        val res = iterator.map(row => {
          wrapped.output(row).toDoubleVector
        })
        res
      })
    } else {
      df.mapPartitions(iterator => {
        val inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("BB.hdf5")
        val multiLayerNetwork: MultiLayerNetwork = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(inputStream, false)
        val wrapped: ParallelInference = new ParallelInference.Builder(multiLayerNetwork).build()
        val res = iterator.map(row => {
          wrapped.output(row).toDoubleVector
        })
        res
      })
    }
```